# how to redraw screen (with cursor at top like `zt`) from autocommand

Tags: autocmd

When I open a `.task` file I don't want to see all the comments at the top.  I want the screen to be scrolled down...  I can do that manually when vim's already running via `zt` and I want this to be done automatically when the file is loaded.

I have an autocommand but it won't act on `zt` or `normal zt`:

This works `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile task.*.task normal 23G22|` but I'm not able to then get the screen to redraw.

I've tried:

```
  function GotoTaskLine()
    normal 23G22|
    normal zt
  endfunction
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile task.*.task call GotoTaskLine()
```

and I've tried these variations:

```
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile task.*.task normal 23G22| | zt
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile task.*.task normal 23G22| zt
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile task.*.task normal 23G22| | normal zt
  autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile task.*.task normal 23G22| normal zt
```

but none of them successfully do both: navigate to line23/column22 *and* redraw screen with cursor position at the top.

Is there another way `zt` can be invoked?  In reading through `:help redraw` and `:help zt` I wasn't able to find anything that pointed me towards freedom.  Can you shine any light here?

Comment: No need to use `|`, `:h :bar` is used to separate ex commands, not normal commands.  Use `normal!` to avoid `remap` , use `s:`  to restrict function to script scope. And group your `autocmd` in `autogroup`.

Comment: @dedowsdi can you provide an answer?

Comment: Just tried your example (not those variations), except I use `*.task` instead of `task.*.task` , it works fine.

Comment: @dedowsdi it does not when opening a new file, it seems.

Comment: @Biggybi New file is blank,  did you mean new buffer? new buffer works fine for me.

Comment: @dedowsdi I did indeed. Just removing `normal` from `normal zt` did the trick though! I un-deleted my wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

```
augroup SkipTaskComments
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType taskedit autocmd! BufEnter,BufRead <buffer> silent!
        \ normal 12gg22|zt
augroup end
```

`normal zt` was wrong, should be `zt` only.

The `augroup` is for convenience. `autocmd!` will delete it's content if you source your `vimrc`, preventing pile-up.

I added an extra autocmd to check the buffer type, and apply your commands to the `<buffer>`. I think it's cleaner. `silent!` is totally optional, that's just how I usually write that type of autocmd.

You can replace `<buffer>` with your original regex if this is really needed

```
au FileType taskedit au! BufEnter,BufRead task*.*task silent!
```

Or even just remove the guilty `normal` from your code

```
autocmd BufEnter,BufRead task*.*task
    \ normal 12gg22|zt
```

You should keep the `augroup`, though.

Comment: The  `|`  between `12gg22|` and `zt` is a mistake, you don't need to use `|` to connect normal commands.

Comment: Oh yeah, sure, edited - thanks!

Comment: Space is also significant. If I read that right, you'll end up in column 23 (or line 13 if 22 was last character on line 12) after that space there. Also, why `12gg` instead of `12G`? There was nothing wrong with using `G` here. In fact, it's even shorter.

Comment: Yup. It was on two lines when I copied it, hence the mistakes. `gg` vs `G` does not really matter, it's just the way I use that command so it looks more familiar to my eyes.

Comment: Apparently the buffer events I had were wrong too, `BufEnter` was required and I deleted `BufNewFile`.  Thanks for the explanations <3